# Laravel update model instead save new

Tags: laravel, model, save

I'm using Laravel 5.1 and I have this code:

```
$settings = new Setting;
            $settings = $user->settings()->first();
            $settings->user_id = $id;
            $settings->save();
```

and this code update `user` model and does not save new. How I can save NEW not update?

Comment: what is `$user` here in second line?

Comment: Do you mean you want to save the `settings` model? Please add the full code.

Comment: @SundarBan         $user = Auth::user();

Comment: @BharatGeleda Yes, I want to save settings model

Comment: Are you just trying to save user_id in the setting table? if than remove ` $settings = $user->settings()->first();` this line.

Comment: no, I want to copy user settings with different user_id

Comment: Checkout the answer. That should work. The only problem was that you were referencing the existing Eloquent model in the second line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the name of the variable in which you're fetching the settings like this

```
$settings_old = $user->settings()->first();
$settings = $settings_old->replicate(); 
$settings->user_id = $id;
$settings->save();
```

Comment: not work... just update the settings, do not add new row in database

Comment: I've updated and used the `replicate()` method. Try this.